# Random number generation / which algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, cryptography

We need to migrate to a better RNG or RBG for some key value generation which will be further used for encryption of the data.

Which will be the most suitable algorithm? Shall I consider NIST doc for this?

Comment: Note that [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com) is better suited for general discussions on cryptographically secure random number generators.

Answer (score 0):

Any pseudo random number generator that produces a Gaussian distribution and that has a wide output (say at least 32 bits) should be enough for creating keys. It's up to you to determine your needs and then find a matching RNG.

For more info, see http://www.random.org/randomness.

Depending on the language you choose to implement this, I'm sure you can find source code for pseudo-RNG on the Web, if the one built-in into your system isn't good enough.

Comment: You don't just need a pseudo random number generator for generating keys, you need to seed the RNG with a good random seed. Finding a suitable PRNG is only half of the story (and the easy part at that).

Comment: A classical random seed is the timestamp when your application starts.

Comment: That depends on the granularity. If your timestamp has a 1-second granularity, then obviously that's not a good choice for key generation. If you have a timestamp that's 1/1000 of a second accurate, then I'd say that's a good choice. And of course you can salt it any way you want.

Comment: No, salts should be random. Timers are prone to attack, and are often inaccurate. There are countless examples of bad or duplicate keys because timers were used as seed or as random value.

Answer (score 0):

As we are a programming site, I would seriously look at the secure random number generators at your disposal in your particular runtime environment. In general you will have to rely on system resources to generate randoms, at least to seed the pseudo random number generator. The only possible exception are CPU specific random instructions, such as the ones used on the latest Intel CPU's (hopefully well-tested secure RNGs will become a main feature of CPU's).

Within many programming environments there is very little choice but to use OpenSSL or `/dev/random` for seeding. In general it is hard to find useful information about the random number generator. Sometimes the RNG is really not suitable at all (e.g. the native PHP version).

If possible, try to find something that conforms to NIST requirements.